# Permutation And Combination method in MathJax using Asscii Code

Tags: mathjax

Need a Permutation And Combination `mathJaX` symbol for the  `nCr and nPr`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
nCk => {}_n \mathrm{ C }_k

nPk => {}_n \mathrm{ P }_k
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Could you add some explanation?

Comment: it is the mathJaX synthax for combination (nCk) and permutation (nPk)

Comment: I modified the above to but the n on top: {}^n \mathrm{ C }_k

Answer (score 4):

You can use
`{n \choose r}` or `\binom{n}{r}`